# "Content-Disposition" and file name in headers with AngularJS

Tags: java, angularjs, web-services, rest

I use angularjs 1.3.14

I have a java REST services produce a xml file with this header: "Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=yourFileName";

I need take the file with the name of my file on AngularJS.

I have this code:

```
$http.get('/someUrl').success(function(data, status, headers){
var myHeaders = headers();
...
});
```

but in myHeaders have only {content-type="application/xml"}. **I need find "Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=yourFileName"**

**Java Services:**

```
@GET
@Path(EXPORT_URL)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
public Response export(@Context HttpServletRequest request) {
    String userName = request.getRemoteUser();
    if (userName != null) {
        ...
        ResponseBuilder response = Response.ok(myObject);
        response.header("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=myFile.xml");
        return response.build();
    } else {
        return Response.status(Status.FORBIDDEN).build();
    }
}
```

Comment: You should set the "Content-Disposition" header on your response.
Can you post some of your java code ?

Comment: try this `response.header("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=myFile.xml");`

Comment: I change "attachment; by "inline; but do not work again

Comment: You can use tools like [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/download/fiddler/fiddler2) (or anyone else) to see wether your response has the correct headers set. And then be more specific on your questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2 years after, I find a solution:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/export", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
public ResponseEntity<String> export(...

HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setAccessControlExposeHeaders(Collections.singletonList("Content-Disposition"));
headers.set("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + filename);
return new ResponseEntity<>(exportedContent, headers, HttpStatus.OK);
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a server side CORS issue. You need to enable this:

```
"Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "Content-Disposition"
```